# How to combine two text files into one with a specific format with shell script?

Tags: shell, text-files, solaris

I'm trying to combine two files into one file with a specific format, the files contain the following:

fileA.txt:

2

1

1

...

fileB.txt:

0023412322

1241231132

1234411177

...

So the output should be:
fileC.txt:

A B

2           0023412322

1           1241231132

1           1234411177

...

Where A and B represent the name of the column, and also form the initial line of the output file

The script should run on Solaris but I'm also having trouble with the instruction awk and I have not allowed to change or install anything on the system. Now I have a solution using a loop but not very efficient because the script takes too long with large files. So aside from using the awk instruction and loops, any suggestions?

I could never use an awk instruction so I do not have an awk instruction, only the loop:

echo "A B" > fileC.txt

i=`echo 1`

for line in `cat fileA.txt`

```
do

    VAR=`sed -n "$i"',1p' fileB.txt`

    echo "$line $VAR" >> fileC.txt

    echo "$VAR" >> file"$line".txt #Another neccesary command for the script 

    i=`expr $i + 1`
```

done

What changes should I do?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (both awk and the loop)

Comment: Is in the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is a very handy program that does almost exactly what you want, short of printing out the filenames or writing to a file.  I wrote this simple shell script to add the filenames:

```
echo -e "$1\t$2" # print the filenames separated by a tab
paste $1 $2
```

You can run this by using `chmod` to make it executable, then running `./myscript file1 file2` (assuming that you name the script `myscript`).  If you want to write to a third file, you can do `./myscript file1 file2 > file3`.

Note that as written, the contents of each file are separated by tabs.  If you want them to instead be separated by spaces, you can use this script instead:

```
echo "$1 $2"
paste -d" " $1 $2
```